# C Linux printf mangled result

Tags: c, linux, terminal, printf

I am having some issues whenever the user inputs a pipe "|" character the output becomes all mangled, I have already tried flushing the buffer to no avail.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char userInput[2000];
    while(1)
    {
        printf("Please Enter Your Input:");
        scanf("%s", userInput);
        printf("%s\n", userInput);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Code looks fine to me.

Comment: It scans one white space delimited word at a time. So if there are spaces in the input it's a little awkward.

Comment: Can you show an input and corresponding output? "Here is what I got, and this is what I was expecting" is usually helpful.

Comment: There's nothing that should cause problems with the `|` character. Can you copy-and-paste the output for a run of the program? One unlikely possibility: could `|` be mapped to something in your tty settings? Run `stty` to see your settings. But as @CharlieBurns says, you *will* get a bit of a mess if there are spaces in your input. Try typing `"1 2 3 4"` as input; is that the same kind of mess you get with `|`?

Comment: Are you reading from a keyboard or a piped input?

Comment: Test the result of `scanf`; it may fail!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things you can do to debug this. First - read in the entire input line, rather than the first word. The safe way to do this is with `getline()` - it will notice if the line is too long for your input buffer, and adjust things (updated with thanks to Elchonon Edelson)

```
char *myString;
int stringLength;
size_t bufLength=0;
myString = NULL; // let getline() adjust the string
stringLength = getline(&myString, &bufLength, stdin)
```

Next, print out the line as entered:

```
printf("The line is <<%s>>\n", myString);
```

Note the use of `<<` and `>>` to show where the string starts / ends - see white space etc.

Finally, print out the string one character at a time, including the hex code:

```
for(ii = 0; ii < stringLength; ii++) {
  char ch;
  ch = myString[ii];
  printf("myString[%d]: character '%c', hex code %02x\n", ii, ch, ch);
}
```

This should help you pinpoint the problem.

Comment: Also, compile with all warnings and debugging info (`gcc -Wall -g`) and learn how to **use the `gdb` debugger**

Comment: Happy to see you accepted the answer - meaning that you must have figured out what was wrong. Would you tell us what you discovered?

Comment: This is wrong. The [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) function is specified to take a `size_t *`, not an `int`. (Also, the `getline()` function takes care of making sure there's enough room for the terminaling null character, so telling it the buffer is smaller than it really is, is pointless, and your code never attempts to append a null character either, so again, telling it the buffer is smaller than its actual size, is, again, pointless.)

Comment: Other notes regarding `getline()`: It isn't necessary to `malloc()` a buffer just to hand it to the function, unless you've already got a general-purpose buffer hanging around you might as well just pass it a pointer to a NULL pointer. In fact, direct quote from the POSIX docs: _Setting_ *lineptr _to a null pointer and_ *n _to zero are allowed and a recommended way to start parsing a file._

Comment: Also, at no point does the POSIX specification actually _say_ what the `getline()` function will do to the second argument, although the only rational explanation is that if it resizes your buffer, the new size will be stored there.

Comment: @elchononedelson - thanks for pointing out those mistakes. I will edit my answer as soon as I get to a computer.

Comment: Honestly, my personal opinion is that `getline()` is generally unnecessary, on the grounds that if the input line doesn't fit in my buffer, someone's just messing around with me, and the rest of the line should be discarded. (Alternately, I can just process the line one buffer-sized chunk at a time. This is gentler on memory usage, as well.)